How to distribute Redis read/write operations with mikebronner/laravel-model-caching
We are currently using mikebronner/laravel-model-caching (https://github.com/mikebronner/laravel-model-caching) for app development in Laravel.
In order to achieve load balancing, we would like to distribute Redis fetch and store operations to read/write connections.
If anyone has expertise in this area, please share the method with us.
If additional information is needed, we will provide it.
Thank you.
Additional information:
Laravel version is 10.13.0
Redis is not in cluster mode

We tried configuring the following settings:

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            [
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => 0,
                'persistent' => true,
                'alias' => 'master'
            ],
            [
                'host' => env('REDIS_READONLY_HOST', env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1')),
                'password' => env('REDIS_READONLY_PASSWORD', env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)),
                'port' => env('REDIS_READONLY_PORT', env('REDIS_PORT', 6379)),
                'database' => 0,
                'persistent' => true,
                'alias' => 'readonly'
            ],
        ],

        'options' => [
            'replication' => true
        ]
    ],


We also attempted to create a new trait using the Cacheable trait.

